# Length of colNames <> colModel! error in JQGRID

Tags: jqgrid

I am using data of following format in jqgrid "1201.2564.2548.25456". This throws the following error while displaying the data from JSON: Length of colNames <> colModel! 
ANy idea.. is it related to format of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parameters `colNames` and `colModel` are arrays, which have to have the same number of elements (the length). You use *different* length. One of possible error which I have seen before was the usage of strings `"[...]"` instead of arrays `[...]` as the value of `colNames` and `colModel`. As the result jqGrid code compared the length of the strings `colNames` and `colModel` instead of comparing the number of elements in arrays `colNames` and `colModel`. Such error could take place if you returns `colNames` and `colModel` from the server and you have used wrong JSON serialization on the server side.

Thus you should verify that the type of `colNames` and `colModel` are arrays and both arrays have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to match the **count** of **columns** with the entries in the `colModel`.

Following error is prompted majorly **if the columns count is not equal** to number of entries inside the `colModel`. So `colModel` should match the count of `ColNames`.

E.g.

```
colNames: ['ID', 'First', 'Last', 'Email'],

colModel: [
      { name: "ID", index: "id", width: 100 },
      { name: "FirstName", index: "firstName", width: 100 },
      { name: "LastName", index: "lastName", width: 100 },
      { name: "Email", index: "email", width: 100 }
           ],
```